# Create field validations using a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule

I am trying to create a field validation that would prevent a user from selecting a checkbox until certain fields are filled out. In other words, the fields cannot be blank or null. I tried using a validation rule but there are too many cross object relationships. Here is the error that I'm getting: "Error 'Maximum of 15 object references on Object Name. You must remove at least 1 relationships' when you create a formula."

Does anyone know how I can create a validation like this using a flow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain this: `I tried using a validation rule but there are too many cross object relationships.`. Do you get an error when saving the validation rule? If yes, please update the question with an appropriate screenshot. Using a validation rule for this would be an easiest and maintainable solution.

Comment: Hi Raul, this is the error that I'm getting: Error 'Maximum of 15 object references on Object Name. You must remove at least 1 relationships' when you create a formula